# Stop no-unused-expressions on svelte $ assignments

Tags: eslint, svelte, typescript-eslint

I'm trying to setup an ESLint using the libs eslint, typescript-eslint (along with its parser) & eslint-plugin-svelte, but each time I write something along the lines of

```
$: somevar, somefunction();
```

ESLint (@typescript-eslint) triggers

> @typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions

I would like to find a way not to remove this rule (but remove this warning) as it seems like a useful for other usecases than this one, but haven't found any solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the warning by letting Svelte track the dependencies within the function:

```js
$: somefunction = () => {
  console.log(somevar);
}
```

(Can potentially cause issues if it tracks things you did not mean to track. Could extract those parts to a static function.)

Answer (score 0):

I've written a [used.ts](https://github.com/bfanger/svelte-preprocess-react/blob/main/src/lib/used.ts) utility:

```
/* eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars */
export default function used(...args: any[]) {}
```

It's part of [svelte-preprocess-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-preprocess-react), but instead of
`import { used } from "svelte-preprocess-react"` I'd recommend creating a used.ts file in your project.

Then after importing you'll be able to write:

```
$: used(somevar), somefunction();
```

and ESLlint won't complain anymore.

In most cases the `somefunction` also does something with the value of `somevar`, in those cases it can be passed as an argument.